Flutter drive hanging on Github actions with no output
We have a job set up in Github Actions to run the flutter integration tests, however once the tests apparently start to run, they hang on forever, after 20 something minutes I get this output
DriverError: Error while reading FlutterDriver result for command: window.$flutterDriver('{"command":"request_data","timeout":"1200000"}')
Original error: Exception: Expected: not null
  Actual: <null>

Original stack trace:
#0      _matcherExpect (package:webdriver/support/async.dart:92:3)
#1      Clock.waitFor (package:webdriver/support/async.dart:60:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterWebConnection.sendCommand (package:flutter_driver/src/driver/web_driver.dart:327:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      WebFlutterDriver.sendCommand (package:flutter_driver/src/driver/web_driver.dart:123:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterDriver.requestData (package:flutter_driver/src/driver/driver.dart:549:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      integrationDriver (package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart:80:29)
<asynchronous suspension>

the set up is pretty simple
name: Flutter Integration Tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
    - name: Create secrets config file
      run: |
        touch secrets.json && echo ${{ secrets.SECRETS_JSON }} | base64 -d > secrets.json
        
    - name: Cache Chromedriver
      uses: actions/cache@v4
      with:
        path: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
        key: chromedriver-${{ runner.os }}-v123

    - name: install chromedriver
      uses: nanasess/setup-chromedriver@v2
      with:
        # Optional: do not specify to match Chrome's version
        chromedriver-version: '124.0.6367.60'

    - name: Run chrome driver
      run: |
        chromedriver --version
        chromedriver --port=4444 &
    
    - name: Setup Flutter SDK
      uses: flutter-actions/setup-flutter@v3
      with:
        channel: stable
        version: 3.19.0
    - run: which flutter

    - name: flutter steps
      run: |
        dart pub global activate flutter_cors
        fluttercors --disable
        flutter config --enable-web
        flutter pub get

    - name: Run Tests with Chrome
      run: |
        flutter drive \
          --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
          --target=integration_test/main_test.dart \
          --dart-define=E2E_TESTS=true \
          --dart-define-from-file="secrets.json" \
          -d web-server \
          --browser-name=chrome \
          --web-browser-flag="--no-sandbox" \
          --web-browser-flag="--disable-audio-input" \
          --web-browser-flag="--use-fake-device-for-media-stream" \
          --web-browser-flag="--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream" \
          --web-browser-flag="--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=test/testing_audio.wav"

When I run this locally It runs without any problem, completing the tests successfully, why is this happening in the host machine? has anyone had similar issues? Thanks in advance
this is the test for reference:
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:scribe/components/buttons.dart';
import 'package:scribe/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  const String automationPassword =
      String.fromEnvironment('AUTOMATION_PWD', defaultValue: "");

  String generateRandomSuffix(int length) {
    const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    final random = Random();
    return String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
        length, (_) => chars.codeUnitAt(random.nextInt(chars.length))));
  }

  void disableOverflowErrors() {
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
      final exception = details.exception;
      final isOverflowError = exception is FlutterError &&
          !exception.diagnostics.any((e) =>
              e.value.toString().startsWith("A RenderFlex overflowed by"));

      if (isOverflowError) {
        print(details);
      } else {
        FlutterError.presentError(details);
      }
    };
  }

  Future<void> desktopLoginFlow(WidgetTester tester) async {
    final toggleButton = find.byKey(const ValueKey('desktop_login_button'));
    await tester.tap(toggleButton);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    final emailInput = find.byKey(const ValueKey('email_input'));
    await tester.enterText(emailInput, "automated_user@yahoo.com");
    final passwordInput = find.byKey(const ValueKey('password_input'));
    await tester.enterText(passwordInput, automationPassword);
    final confirmLoginButton = find.descendant(
      of: find.byKey(const ValueKey('confirm_login_button')),
      matching: find.byType(InkWell),
    );
    await tester.tap(confirmLoginButton);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    expect(find.text("Start recording"), findsOne);
  }

  testWidgets("Create main Scribe recording", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    disableOverflowErrors();
    app.main();
    // Trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.text('Login'), findsOne);
    await desktopLoginFlow(tester);
  });
}


I'm facing the same issue, any progress?

use --profile flag to see if it works @sina.s

Issue raised here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/155019, please upvote the issue on GitHub and also this comment.
